# How do I automatically start supervisor on boot in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, supervisord, rc.d

Is there a pre-existing startup script for [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/) on FreeBSD? If not, is there a good guide for writing `rc.d` scripts for FreeBSD? I'm pretty new to the platform.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

I now have the following in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/supervisord`, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not seeing anything in the startup scroll related to supervisord.

```
#!/bin/sh

# PROVIDE: supervisord
# REQUIRE: LOGIN
# KEYWORD: shutdown

. /etc/rc.subr

name="supervisord"
rcvar=`set_rcvar`
load_rc_config "$name"

command="/usr/local/bin/${name}"
command_args="-c /usr/local/etc/supervisord.conf"

supervisord_enable=${supervisord_enable-"NO"}
supervisord_pidfile=${supervisord_pidfile-"/var/run/supervisord.pid"}

pidfile="${supervisord_pidfile}"

run_rc_command "$1"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you installed supervisord from ports (`sysutils/py-supervisor`) you should have a functioning rc script in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/supervisord`

Check the script for info/other configuration parameters, but simply adding `supervisord_enable="YES"` to `/etc/rc.conf` should be all you need to do to make it start automatically on boot.

Comment: Is there a port for supervisord? `make search name="supervisord"` doesn't show any results.

Comment: Yup - it's actually called py-supervisor for some odd reason (sysutils/py-supervisor)

Comment: Can you edit to put the name of the port in the answer proper? I'd do it myself, but my rep isn't high enough.

Answer (score 6):

If you installed supervisord from the port `sysutils/py-supervisor` then this rc file is already present... (than to voretaq7 for pointing this out).

The basic framework of a rc file is:

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/rc.subr

name="supervisord"
rcvar=`set_rcvar`
load_rc_config "$name"

command="/usr/local/bin/${name}"
command_args=""

run_rc_command "$1"
```

Creating the file `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/supervisord` with the above, then chmodding it `+x` will get you started (probably).
I am assuming you have `supervisord` installed in `/usr/local/bin`, change that path as necessary. Also you can add any command line arguements you need (like a configuration file or whatever). I'm not familiar with supervisord, so I'm not sure what it needs.

**Make sure you  have a line in `/etc/rc.conf` similar to `supervisord_enable="YES"` or the script will do precisely nothing.**

Comment: See also this article on writing FreeBSD rc scripts: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/rc-scripting/ -- Everything you ever wanted to know about the RC system but were afraid to ask.